# Invalid conversion from 'DWORD' to 'const char *'

Tags: c++, winapi, type-conversion

I'm trying to compile some code, but I'm getting an error:

> Error invalid conversion from `DWORD` to `const char *`

Here's the code I'm trying to compile:

```
hWindow = FindWindow(NULL, "Window");    
if (hWindow){
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWindow, &pid);
}
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pid);
if(hProcess != NULL) {
    SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(MyWindow, MyStatic), pid);
}
```

How do I convert a `DWORD` to a `const char *`?

Comment: SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(MyWindow, MyStatic), pid);   the pid causes the error, guess you cant use dwords here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(MyWindow, MyStatic), pid);
```

`pid` is a DWORD (as you used it in `GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWindow, &pid)` which takes a `LPDWORD` as the second argument). However, `SetWindowText` expects a C-string as it's second argument, so instead of `pid`, you must pass a value of type `char *` or `char []`.

To display the value of `pid`, you can make use of `sprintf`:

```
char * str = new char[10];
sprintf(str,"%d",pid);
```

You may have to modify the size of `str` a little (10 might be too small, or bigger than necessary - that's up to you and your situation).

Comment: you know any good way to do that without using string steams, ben trying forever.

Comment: @user1218395: Just added a `sprintf` example.

Comment: doesnt compile cannot convert 'char**' to 'char*' in initialization| doesnt like your first line

Comment: Don't forget to release the allocated memory (allocated by `new char[10]`): `delete str`. Instead of allocating dynamic memory, you can use a local variable that doesn't need to be freed: `char str[10];`

Answer (score 4):

`SetWindowText` expects a `const char *` (i.e. a C-string) and you are passing it a number (`pid`), it's obvious that you get an error.

The standard C++ way to perform the conversion is to use a string stream (from header `<sstream>`:

```
std::ostringstream os;
os<<pid;
SetDlgItemText(MyWindow, MyStatic, os.str().c_str());
```

(here I used `SetDlgItemText` instead of `GetDlgItem`+`SetWindowText` to save typing, but it's the same thing)

Alternatively, you can use `snprintf`.

```
char buffer[40];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%u", pid);
SetDlgItemText(MyWindow, MyStatic, buffer);
```

Comment: any other way then using String Streams #include <sstream> makes my output to big

Comment: What output are you talking about? Are you talking about final executable size? Have you enabled optimizations in your compiler (="release mode" or whatever)?

Comment: yes i think it may be a bug with GCC, yah im in release mode using stip debugs and all optimizations my final exe is 25kb without sstream and 450kb with it

Comment: 425kb increase looks like 90% bigger?

Comment: This is really strange... on my Linux machine using just that stuff from the string streams generates a 13 KB executable, which is just 5 KB more than a Hello World.

Comment: Still, I updated my answer to include the C-style (`snprintf`) solution.

Comment: maybe because im using Windows

Comment: Which version of gcc are you using?

Comment: not even sure probally the stable one, Im using Code::Blocks just switched over from VB6 and c++ is working alot better for me. Btw your code workd!! Thanks my output size is now 35kb

Comment: Btw in vb6 i could do Buffer = "The Result Is" & Buffer      is their a way i could add more to buffer like this in c++

Comment: @user1218395 : Yes -- use `std::stringstream` as has just been demonstrated!

Comment: snprintf works well for chaining together data types into a string as well. There are a few examples on this page.

Comment: @chris: although you must be very careful not to overflow the buffer. That's why I usually prefer `std::string` and `std::stringstream`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, isn't that why you provide the maximum number of characters to write?

Comment: @chris: you should add extra logic to handle the case where the static buffer isn't long enough - avoiding a buffer overflow is good, but getting a truncated string often is not acceptable.