# C++ SetDlgItemText Error

Tags: c++, windows

i am new to C++ and am trying to set an Editbox text with a Int.
Using this code

```
int MyInt = 100;
SetDlgItemText(MyWindow, EditKills, MyInt);
```

I am getting this error below

```
In function 'BOOL DialogProc(HWND__*, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)':|
invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const CHAR*'|
```

Update Solved.
I used this code if anyone else has this problem and needs help.

```
int MyInt = 100;
SetDlgItemInt(MyWindow, EditKills, MyInt, TRUE);
```

Comment: Please show the complete code. What is MyWindow, EDitKills and GotValue? show us the dialogproc call

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the same as the answer to your question [Invalid conversion from 'DWORD' to 'const char *'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746706/invalid-conversion-from-dword-to-const-char)

C++ does not automatically convert any type to a string.  You'll have to do that manually with `sprintf`.

```
case CSETimer:
int GotValue;
ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (void*)(MYBASE + 0x728), &GotValue, 4, NULL);
char GotValueStr[10];
sprintf(GotValueStr, "%d", GotValue);
SetDlgItemText(MyWindow, EditKills, GotValueStr);    return TRUE;
```

Comment: Also, you can use _itoa-functions for conversion from int to c-string. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0we9x30h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As per your code the variable GotValue is int . You need to convert into to LPCTSTR and pass it as the third argument of your SetDlgItemText function

```
char szBuf[MAX_PATH]={0};
_snprintf(szBuf, MAX_PATH-1,"%d",GotValue);
```

or use [itoa_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0we9x30h%28VS.80%29.aspx)

or

```
std::ostringstream oss;

oss <<GotValue;

std::string s(oss.str());
s.c_str()
```